# C++ boost logging compile error (linux)

Tags: c++, linux, boost

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Running this on the console yields the following error:

> `#` c++ -I /var/local/boost_1_46_1/ log.cpp -o log -lboost-log
>   log.cpp: In function âvoid init()â:
>   log.cpp:11: error: âboost::loggingâ has not been declared
>   log.cpp:13: error: âboost::fltâ has not been declared
>   log.cpp:13: error: âloggingâ has not been declared
>   log.cpp:13: error: âloggingâ has not been declared

I've also tried it explicitly linking the libraries from both stage and /usr/local/lib directories.

My log.cpp:

```
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/filters.hpp>

using namespace std;

void init()
{
    boost::logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        boost::flt::attr< boost::logging::trivial::severity_level >("Severity") >= boost::logging::trivial::info
    );

}

}

int main(int, char*[]) {
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";
}
```

This code will compile if I leave out the `void init()` function...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need the following namespace redefinitions to use the tutorials:

```
namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace fmt = boost::log::formatters;
namespace flt = boost::log::filters;
namespace attrs = boost::log::attributes;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;
```

http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/how_to_read.html

Comment: I'm still getting errors, I'll update the original post with the changes I've made.

Comment: My bad, the tutorials redefine namespaces.  I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your `#include` is right? Try `#include <boost/log/core/core.hpp>`.

Comment: Ya, there are 2 core.hpps, one in boost/log and one in boost/log/core. The one core.hpp I include above includes the other like so:

#include <boost/log/core/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core/record.hpp>